# Why am I getting this warning with Travis-CI about module being undefined?

Tags: javascript, travis-ci

Find the Travis-CI page [here](https://travis-ci.org/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/builds/103431790)

```
         } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
                                                      ^ 'module' is not defined.
           module.exports = function( root, jQuery ) {
               ^ 'module' is not defined.
>> 2 errors in 1 file
Warning: Task "jshint:main" failed. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

It's clearly that both of those occurrences are module are protected by an *if* statement or [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This is perfectly valid, why would it generate a warning?

Comment: It's complaining that you have no declaration of the variable named `module`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variables before you use them to make JSLint happy. So you need a

```
var module;
```

declaration before the code in question.

Comment: Why do I have to do that? I want to test if it's an object, not create it. If I create it it could impact other code...

Comment: The declaration doesn't create anything, it just indicates that the variable exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion arises from being accustomed to running JavaScript to get this result.  As stated by @Barmar already, you have a simple undeclared variable.  jshint is not evaluating the check in the first half of your if statement; it's just complaining that `module` hasn't been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare `module`.
You need to add this to your jshint config

`/*jshint node:true */`

Comment: The test is happening under the nodejs runtime, and uses the CommonJS spec of module exporting. You'll need to tell the jshint that it's ok to have that syntax. Adding `{ "node": true }` to the `.jshintrc` or adding `/*jshint node:true */` to the top of the file.